# why my HTML button doesn't trigger start function?

Tags: javascript, json, api

I am using echo nest API and can't find the problem with my button, why doesn't  trigger my function at all! I check my button in chrome debug and shows no activity.

If I enter it trigger the function, but when I click on the button it doesn't trigger my function ?!!!

I need another pair of eyes to check my codes , pleaseeee :)

Thank you!

```
//Search artists.
  function search(){      
      inputField = document.getElementById("inputField");

      callApiSearch ( urlRoot + inputField , parseData);

    }

        //register click event handler for searchButton
      function start(){
          var searchButton = document.getElementById( "searchButton" );
          searchButton.addEventListener("click", search, false); 
        } // end function start

        window.addEventListener( "load", start, false );  
    </script>   



    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="searchForm" action="#">
    <center>
    <table>
        <thead style="align-text:center" ><img src="images/Logo.png" style="align:center"><br/></thead>

        <tr>
            <td>Search Artist:</td>
            <td> <input id="inputField" type="search"> </td>
            <td> <input id="searchButton" type="button" value="Search"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
            <div id="results"></div>
    </center>
        </form>



    </body>
    </html>
```

in chrome --- > F12 --- > Network 
should display all the activities; however mine is empty ... please correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: Its working in chrome, I checked it in my machine. Could you provide a fildde DEMO?

Comment: Where are `urlRoot` and `parseData` defined??

Comment: Try moving the script to the bottom of the page

Comment: @ShaikMahaboobBasha in chrome --- > F12 --- > Network 
should display all the activities; however mine is empty ... please correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: @sabof thank you, didin't work :(

Comment: @null I just didn't add them to my question !

Comment: You should put break points in Sources tab and verify the method is getting called or not. What's the point with Network activities, it does relate to method called or not

Comment: Everything is working fine!!..
I think there is some problem with callApiSearch ( urlRoot + inputField , parseData);

Comment: @NilRad My bad, didn't notice the "load" event binding.

Comment: @sumeet , you might be right I'll check it out again ... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

html

```
<form action="#" id="searchForm" name="searchForm">
        <img src="images/Logo.png" style="align:center" /><br />

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Search Artist:</td>

                <td><input id="inputField" type="search" /></td>

                <td><input id="searchButton" type="button" value=
                "Search" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <div id="results"></div><br />
    </form>
```

javascript

```
$("#searchButton").click(function() {
    inputField = document.getElementById("inputField");
    callApiSearch(urlRoot + inputField, parseData);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your 'script' block at the end of your html code. Browsers parses html document in top-down fashion and when your following method parsed by your browser

```
//register click event handler for searchButton
      function start(){
          var searchButton = document.getElementById( "searchButton" );
          searchButton.addEventListener("click", search, false); 
        } // end function start
```

, it doesnt know what 'searchButton' is, since 'searchButton' hasn't been parsed yet. Thus it is unable to add event listener to your button and it doesn't work on click

Comment: didn't work. The problem is when I enter it runs, but when I click on the button it doesn't trigger ?!!!